# Incorrect Summing Value

Tags: sql

I'm trying to join a table onto a mapping table. The mapping table has geographical data in it and the idea is that it will look at the most detail first i.e. Postalcode and mapp, if postal code has not been provided it will look at the zone:

```
ID  Region  Country Description Zone    County      City            Postal_Code
9324    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Western Shore   7000
9325    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Western Shore   7004
9326    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Western Shore   7005
9327    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Western Shore   7007
9328    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Western Shore   7008
9329    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Western Shore   7009
9330    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Western Shore   7010
9331    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Western Shore   7011
9332    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Western Shore   7012
9333    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Eastern Shore   7015
9334    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Eastern Shore   7016
9335    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Western Shore   7017
9336    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Eastern Shore   7018
9337    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Eastern Shore   7019
9338    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Eastern Shore   7020
9339    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Eastern Shore   7021
9340    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Eastern Shore   7022
9341    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Eastern Shore   7023
9342    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Eastern Shore   7024
9343    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Sorell          7025
9344    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Sorell          7026
9345    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Sorell          7027
9346    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Western Shore   7030
9347    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Kingston        7050
9348    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Kingston        7052
9349    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Kingston        7053
9350    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Kingston        7054
9351    Australasia Australia   Tasmania    70      Kingston        7055
```

The idea is that everything comes back to Zone and Description but the joining is dependent of the data provided so the data that I'm trying to format is:

```
COUNTRY STATE   Zone        ZIP     TIV
Australia   NULL    70      NULL    1000000
Australia   NULL    70      NULL    1000000
Australia   NULL    70      NULL    1000000
Australia   NULL    70      NULL    1000000
Australia   NULL    NULL    7023    100000
```

So the answer looks like this:

```
COUNTRY Zone    NAME    Value
Australia   70  Tasmania    4000000
```

However the code I have is:

```
SELECT  GR.COUNTRY,
        GR.ZONE,
        GR.Zone_Desc AS NAME,
        sum(TA.TIV)

FROM [dbo].[Tmp_Format] TA

INNER JOIN [dbo].[GeoRes_Mapping] GR ON TA.COUNTRY = GR.Country AND TA.Zone = GR.Zone

WHERE TA.COUNTRY = 'Australia'

GROUP BY    GR.COUNTRY,
            GR.ZONE,
            GR.Zone_Desc,
            TA.TIV
```

And what I'm actually getting is:

```
COUNTRY  ZONE   NAME    Value
Australia   70  Tasmania    112000000
```

It seems to be multiplying the 4100000 by the 28 different zone in my mapping table? Apologies for this being so long winded but I'm really struggling to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not multiplying by the different zones, but by the postal codes.  You have multiple rows per zone.  Perhaps this will solve your problem:

```
SELECT  GR.COUNTRY, GR.ZONE, GR.Zone_Desc AS NAME, sum(TA.TIV)
FROM [dbo].[Tmp_Format] TA INNER JOIN
     (select distinct country, zone, zone_desc
      from [dbo].[GeoRes_Mapping]
     ) GR
     ON TA.COUNTRY = GR.Country AND TA.Zone = GR.Zone
WHERE TA.COUNTRY = 'Australia'
GROUP BY GR.COUNTRY, GR.ZONE, GR.Zone_Desc;
```

Also, `TIV` shouldn't be in the `group by`.